# Sidebar won't fill 100% height :(

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I apologize ahead of time - I did search for this, and it seems pretty easy, and I tried what I found, but it hasn't worked.

I'm tinkering with a Bootstrap page - and my sidebar won't fill 100% of the page no matter what I try.

On a sidenote, I was using IE10 and it was looking okay - then I opened the page in Firefox and...the form and my badge image squished together ><

I uploaded the page and css to a dummy domain I have - http://blacksunresearch.com/

I would paste the code, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong ><

PS: if it helps, I'm practicing by recreating this page - http://landing.trugreen.com/growth29

Answer (score 1):

The sidebar won't fill "100%" because you have not defined what 100% is, in other words there needs to be a height defined on a parent element in order for height : 100% to work. Other wise 100% is just the data within the div.

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar need a **height** of **100%** (and all the parents)!

On your second site you have used a Trick: The sidebar dont have 100% height, you only used a helper for that.

Comment: This will only give it the same height as the window.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets start with the CSS. Since the column at http://blacksunresearch.com/ has no parent height attribute the height is automatically set to auto for this div. If this page's content isn't going to change you can just hard code in the height you wish.

Now for the site you are trying to mimic at http://landing.trugreen.com/growth29. They are achieving this effect by placing another div under the filled one.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a class for the container row as the following

```
.row.anyclass{
    display:flex;
}
```

but i'm not sure about browser compatibility, sorry i'm using linux =)

further read about display:flex http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: flex seemed to work - at least it did on my computer. I uploaded it up to the server and I see the updated code but it's not working -  a good trick to know though! I'll probably just use a set height since the page isn't going to change much - but it has to be responsive...but I'll get to that lol

Answer (score 0):

Give your containing row a `position:relative`. Then add this css to your sidebar (.kigside):

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

The absolute position forces it out of the flow, but as long as the columns have a set width (which they do), the layout will remain the same. THe `right : 0` attribute positions it back where it's supposed to go. The `top:0` and `bottom:0` attributes force it to fill it's container's height, even if it doesn't have a set height (which it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the style of `height: 100vh;` on the element worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I know that you only mention CSS. But if you are interested in another approach, you could always use javascript and jquery - which I have noticed at the bottom of your source code- to dynamically set the height of your sidebar.

Here is what I have used as a solution to your problem :

```
$('.kigside') .height($('.kigmain') .height());
```

This line takes the height of your main div containing all your paragraphs as a reference for the sidebar's own height.